# Crieria API query using criteriabuilder.construct with a non existing relationship

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Given this very simple DTO:

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String name;

@OneToOne
private Employee boss;

}
```

I'd like to make a query that gathers all employee names and their boss' id, put in a nice clean POJO:

```
public class EmployeeInfo {

private String name;
private Long bossId;

public EmployeeInfo(String name, Long bossId) {
    this.name = name;
    this.bossId = bossId;
}

}
```

This query should be of use:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<EmployeeInfo> query = cb.createQuery(EmployeeInfo.class);
Root<Employee> root = query.from(Employee.class);
query.select(
        cb.construct(EmployeeInfo.class,
                root.get("name").as(String.class),
                root.get("boss").get("id").as(Long.class)));
result = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

When a bossId is present in the employee column this works just fine. But when no boss id is set the record will be completly ignored. So how do i treat this non existing boss relation as null or 0 for the construct/multiselect?

In pure SQL it is easy:

```
SELECT name, COALESCE(boss_id, 0) FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

But for the love of god i cannot make the criteria api do this.

```
cb.construct(EmployeeInfo.class,
        root.get("name").as(String.class),
        cb.coalesce(root.get("boss").get("id").as(Long.class), 0L)));
```

Comment: What if try `root.join("boss", JoinType.LEFT)` instead of `root.get("boss")`. It should work without `coalesce`

Comment: This is it. I'd like to acknowledge your answer, please post a dedicated one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `root.get("boss")` generate query with cross join like this `from Employee employee, Employee boss where employee.boss.id=boss.id`. So records where `employee.boss.id is null` are ignored.

To solve the problem you should use `root.join("boss", JoinType.LEFT)` instead of `root.get("boss")`